# PDOStatement::bindParam, using PDO::PARAM_STR what does the length specify?

Tags: php, pdo

I am writing a query for a sql input statement, i noticed that when using the PDO::PARAM_STR i need to specify a length. From the manual, i see that the length is "Length of the data type. To indicate that a parameter is an OUT parameter from a stored procedure, you must explicitly set the length."

My problem is that I don't understand what an OUT parameter is? If in my MySQl table the field im accessing is a varchar with 128 length, should the length of the PARAM_STR be set to 128? Sorry for my ignorance and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the length when binding an input parameter. Only when you are binding to the output of a function (also read stored procedure) does the length need to be specified (and only on certain DB platforms IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

> If in my MySQl table the field im accessing is a varchar with 128 length, should the length of the PARAM_STR be set to 128?

Yes.